# Selecting Elements in d3 after (this)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3 I'm animating elements based on what they are.

```
.on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
    d3.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('y', function() {
            // affects all <rect> elements
            // I have tried
            if (source.length > (i + 1)) {
                console.log(i);
            }
        }

    d3.select(this)
        .attr('y' function() {
            // affects only the mouseover element
        }

    // since above didn't work, maybe some other selection method will?
    d3.select(AllThingsAfterthis)
        .attr('y' function() {
            // some other values
        }
})
```

I'm using an `on.('mouseover')` event to determine two states:

`d3.selectAll('rect')`

`d3.select(this)`

What I'd like to know is how to select only elements after `this` in the grouping.

```
rect 1 -> .selectAll
rect 2 -> .selectAll
rect 3 -> this
rect 4 -> how do I target this?
rect 5 -> or this specifically?
```

Comment: Add svg markup that you have to the question, this text description is not helpful

Comment: Added code to clarify.  I'm looking for a method in d3 that can target elements who's index is after the this object.

Comment: So you have group (I belive it is `g` tag) and you want to do something with all rects in the group when one of them is hovered over?

Comment: That would be one way, absolutely. But I need to generate that group tag every time a mouse over event as the hover state will be triggering a regeneration. Doesn't seem that efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling):

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
    var node = this;
    while(node = node.nextSibling) {
        d3.select(node)...;
    }
})
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y626N/).